# Android - do something in activity when preferences change

Tags: java, android, android-activity, callback, sharedpreferences

I have two classes, `CustomerPreferences` which `extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and `CustomerActivity` which `extends Activity`.  In `CustomerActivity`, I calculate some values.  In `CustomerPreferences` there's a particular `ListPreference` I want to monitor.  When the user enters `CustomerPreferences`--which is done via a menu option on `CustomerActivity`--and changes that `ListPreference`, then hits the back button and returns to `CustomerActivity`, I want to recalculate my values based on the new preference setting.  If the user goes into `CustomerPreferences` but doesn't change the value of the `ListPreference`, I don't want to recalculate anything upon return to `CustomerActivity`.

How can I do this?

I figure I'll need to do something in `CustomerPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChanged` as well as maybe `CustomerPreferences.onBackPressed`, then probably handle something in `CustomerActivity`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can handle the change in CustomerActivity's onResume() method. So after the user presses back, in onResume(), go through your preferences and recalculate your values and change your GUI representation based on the calculated values.

Sure, sometimes this will be unnecessary as the user may not have changed anything. As long as your calculations aren't too heavy this should not be cause for concern.

Another thing you can do is set a boolean in shared preferences such as preferencesChanged which will get set to true in CustomerPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChanged. Then check preferencesChanged in onResume(). If true do your recalculations. Otherwise do nothing.

Another option is to start the preferences activity for a result with startActivityForResult(). Then do the recalculations in onActivityResult() in CustomerActivity. The result value would be set in CustomerPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChanged

Comment: Doing it in `onResume` worked fine.  :)  Thanks, I'm new to Android development, so I didn't know what to look for.  I knew there'd be something like this, though!

Comment: Before I read this post I used the `onResume()` but I think the  `startActivityForResult()` is better since `onResume()` may be called for many other reasons than exiting Preferences.